# codeigniter - use dependent dropdown with jquery twice in a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have this functioning dependent drop-down, which is used for address, here is my code,

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID" id = "PROV_ID">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" name = 'CT_ID' id = 'CT_ID'>
                <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
            </select>
```

jquery is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
    var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
    console.log(PROVID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

now what i need is to do another one like this in my form, because i need it for residential and permanent address, i did another one like this

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID2" id = "PROV_ID2">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" name = 'CT_ID2' id = 'CT_ID2'>
                <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
            </select>
```

and the jquery is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PROV_ID2").change(function() {
    var PROVID2 = {"PROVID2" : $('#PROV_ID2').val()};
    console.log(PROVID2);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID2,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID2');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i2, option2){
              select.append("<option value='"+option2.CT_ID+"'>"+option2.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

im not that sure with the jquery bec. i am not familiar with it, but i need this one finished asap. what is the error? why is the second dependent drop-down not working? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this for second dropdown, try for first to same thing

```
<select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID2" id = "PROV_ID2" onchange="provchange()">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" name = 'CT_ID2' id = 'CT_ID2'>
                <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
            </select>
```

jquery js

```
function provchange(){
                      var PROV_ID2=$('#PROV_ID2').val();

                      $.ajax({
                         url: "<?php echo base_url('Employees/dependent_dropdown/')?>",
                         type: "post",
                         data : {
                            PROV_ID: PROVID2
                         },
                         success: function(data){
                            var json = JSON.parse(data);
                            //alert(data);
                            $("#CT_ID2").empty();
                            $("#CT_ID2").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', '').text(':: SELECT ::'));
                            ival=0;
                      for (var i in json) {
                         $("#CT_ID2").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', json[i].CT_ID).text(json[i].CITY));
                       }
                         }
                      });

             }
```